# How do I run a program via Ruby and access its standard input and output

Tags: ruby

I have a completely separate Ruby file that reads from Standard Input and writes to Standard Output.

I have certain test cases that I want to try. How do I pass my inputs to Standard Input to the file, and then test the Standard Output against the expected results?

---

As an example, here's the stuff I've already figured out:

There's a file that reads a number from standard input, squares it, and writes it to standard input

`square.rb`:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w

input = STDIN.read

# square it
puts input.to_i ** 2
```

Complete the `pass_input_to_file` method of `test.rb`:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

def pass_input_to_file(input)
  # complete code here
end

class Test < Minitest::Test
  def test_file
    assert_equal pass_input_to_file(2), 4
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Ruby Open3 Library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2) to submit STDIN when calling a ruby script.

```rb
require 'open3'

def pass_input_to_file(input)
  output, _status = Open3.capture2('path_to_script', :stdin_data => input)
  output
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to test this would probably be to have your program look to see if it was passed any arguments first.  Something like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w

input = ARGV[0] || STDIN.read

# square it
puts input.to_i ** 2
```

and then you can shell out to test it:

```
def pass_input_to_file(input)
  `path/to/file #{input}`.to_i
end
```

Otherwise, I would reach for something like [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) to automate a subshell.

---

As an aside, for more complicated programs, using [OptionParser](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) or a CLI gem is probably better than looking at ARGV directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Chris! :) Unfortunately, the `square.rb` file was a stand-in for any kind of file (even non-Ruby) that reads and writes STD IN and OUT, respectively. One that we don't have control over. The `backticks` to execute shell code idea was something I started using immediately after posting this question, but it's more Bash in Ruby that Ruby itself :).

Still a valid way to do it though, and thank you for help!